# Deleting an object-property passed as a function argument

Tags: javascript, properties

I'm trying to delete an object property:

```
var test = {abc: 1};
console.log(delete test.abc); //works fine and returns 'true'
```

The following construct drives me crazy

```
function deleteNode(_node) {
  console.log(delete _node);
}

deleteNode(test.abc); // does not work and returns 'false'
```

Why? I read many questions on stackoverflow regarding trouble with delete and read most of the typical links provided. But I can't find a solution to this simple problem...

Comment: Because JavaScript does not have pass-by-reference. `delete` needs a property reference as its operand.

Comment: You can pass the whole `test` to `deleteNode` and inside do `delete _node.abc`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleting dynamic props of an object could be achieved like this:

```
function deleteNode(obj, key) {
  delete obj[key]
}
```

See the [delete docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) for more details.

When having a "path" like "a.b.c" you can use [lodash unset](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#unset) which deletes nested entries:

```
var object = { 'a': { 'b': { 'c': 7 } } }; 
_.unset(object, 'a.b.c');
```

Use of `eval` is [discouraged](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Do_not_ever_use_eval!) .

Comment: The object keys are randomly created strings (serving as a unique id). I get the fully qualified property "path" as my only input and I'd prefer not to have to "parse" the path for parent object and property...

EDIT: the docs say: obj['key'] and obj.key are equivalent.

Comment: @cl10k can you give an example. Didn't quite get about 'path' you mentioned about.

Comment: Then you might add some more info to your question... please go into more detail, as there is no notion of "path" and "keys" yet.

Comment: I have a fairly deep object structure where I need to create, delete and move new objects (serving as properties for their parent objects). A typical input property would be: data.sensors.deviceA.price (with price as a property of the deviceA subobject)

Comment: @cl10k use `eval`, i updated that in my answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/50819577/1376448. see last code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

```js
    var test = {abc: 1};
    function deleteNode(_node) {
      console.log(delete _node);
    }
    
    deleteNode(test.abc);
```

When you invoked deleteNode above, `test.abc` already resolved to `1` before being passed to function. `deleteNode` is technically invoking `delete 1`. And according to [ES standard](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete), deleting a function argument directly results in `false` or gives an error in **strict** mode.

```js
"use strict";
var test = {a: 1};
function del(a) {
    console.log(delete a);
}
del(test.a);
```

You will need to pass the *object* and *key* as different arguments to method.

```js
    var test = {abc: {a: 1, b: 2, c: {d: 1}}};
    function deleteNode(obj, key) {
      console.log(eval('delete obj.' +key));
    }
    
    deleteNode(test, 'abc.c.d');
    console.log('test is', test)
```